# How to pass the environment specific values to pipeline parameters in azure data factory using Azure DevOps release variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I have created Azure Data Factory using ARM template and then created datasets and pipelines into it.

In one of the pipelines, I have used the parameters(`EmailTo`, `Subject`) with hardcoded values like this below:

```
        {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/pl_xxxxxxxx')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "properties": {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "xxxxxxxxxx_Columns",
                    "type": "Lookup",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "policy": {
                        "timeout": "0.00:01:00",
                        "retry": 3,
                        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 60,
                        "secureOutput": false,
                        "secureInput": false
                    },
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "SqlMISource",
                            "partitionOption": "None"
                        },
                        "dataset": {
                            "referenceName": "ds_xxxxxxxxxxx_New_Columns",
                            "type": "DatasetReference",
                            "parameters": {}
                        },
                        "firstRowOnly": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "foreach_New_Column",
                    "type": "ForEach",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        {
                            "activity": "lkp_xxxxxxxxx_New_Columns",
                            "dependencyConditions": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "items": {
                            "value": "@activity('lkp_xxxxxxxxxxx_New_Columns').output.value",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "pl_Notify_xxxxxxxxxxx_New_Column",
                                "description": "Sends email to xxxxxxxxxxxx.",
                                "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "pipeline": {
                                        "referenceName": "pl_xxxxxxxx_Email_Notification",
                                        "type": "PipelineReference"
                                    },
                                    "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "EmailTo": "xyz1233@abc.com",
                                        "ErrorMessage": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().TABLE_NAME, ',', item().COLUMN_NAME, ' has been added in xxx. Please review. Change will be processed to xxxxx automatically in 7 days.' )",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "PipelineName": {
                                            "value": "@pipeline().Pipeline",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "Subject": {
                                            "value": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "folder": {
                "name": "xxxx/Sub-Pipelines"
            },
            "annotations": [],
            "lastPublishTime": "2021-09-01T19:40:30Z"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
        ]
    },
```

I want to pass the dynamic values to the above parameters based on the environment (Dev, QA etc.….) for the above pipeline parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can use the task [**replacetokens**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) in your release pipeline. It will replace tokens in files with variable values. You can first set all of your variables in libraries (DEV, QA, PROD, ...).
In the ARM template file, you need to specify the token prefix and token suffix like the following:

```
"EmailTo": ${emailAddress}$
```

In your YAML file, the task should look like this (using version 3 for instance):

```
- task: replacetoken@3
  displayName: 'Replace variables'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      *.json
    rootDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/files'
    tokenPrefix: '${'
    tokenSuffix: '}$'
```

Comment: Is it possible to use variables inside the data factory pipeline resource creation code using arm template? If yes, pls update your answer according to it.

Comment: You need to define all of your variables in libraries (variable groups) that you will reference in your release pipeline.  Next, you should specify the name of your variable in the ARM template (wherever you want) and put the token prefix and suffix around it like I specified in the top.